# How can I create a Swift playground like GuidedTour.playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

[GuidedTour Playground](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.playground.zip) contains both interactive and non-interactive elements and nicely formatted text. The text seems to be locked and can't be edited. I found it as an excellent learning tool. Is it possible to edit contents of it or create something similar to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A playground file is a "bundle", i.e. a directory containing files
and subdirectories that appears to the user as a single file.
With "Show Package Contents" in the Finder you can inspect the
structure.

The format is documented:

> [Interactive Learning Document Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Playground_Ref/Chapters/InteractiveLearning.html)
>
> **Warning:** This is a specification that is likely to change.
>
> An interactive learning document is a kind of playground that lets the
> reader interact with code mixed with rich HTML content. Its file
> format is a package that contains Swift source code, HTML content,
> assets such as CSS and images, and a manifest file.

and a detailed description follows.

Comment: Cool! It's like building an ePub